# Django: What is the best way to serve several views of the same data, preferably rendered differently for each?

Tags: django, model-view-controller, templates, view, django-templates

Is it possible?

My problem is, I have several columns on my main-page, all of these columns will need to display the models using different filters, and different models aswell. I dont want to fetch the models and filter it in the view then to pass them as variables to the main-page containing all the "model1_filterAppliedA", "model1_filterAppliedB". That seems overkill. I want a nice way to say "in this column display this filetered queryset of this model" "in that other column display this other queryset using this filter".

What is the best way to achieve that in django?

Thanks

EDIT:

So after experimenting a while;

Option 1:

I have a templatetag which looks like this

```
@register.inclusion_tag('app/accordion_column.html', takes_context=True)
def accordion_by_filter(context, f):
    user = context['request'].user
    print "f: " + str(f)

    filetered_mobjects = Modell.objects \
                            .filter(creator=user.userprofile) \
                            .filter(state=f) \
                            .order_by('-created')[0:10]

    return {'mobjects': filetered_mobjects}
```

Then from my template I call it with

```
{% load mytags %}
{% accordion_by_filter 'A' %}
```

And the accordion_column.html extends my other templates and just loops over the mobjects.
Now when I need to show in main_column all the mobjects but filtered by 'B' I do the same but call it with accordion_by_filter 'B'

So for a index view, which has accordion_column (to the left) main_column and right_sidebar. Three separate hits to the database will be made, for each filter to apply. This is I think okay, since the other option would be to fetch all the mobjects and filter on the result list ?

Option 2; filters, the view which loads any template should fetch all or some models and shovel it along in a variable to the template where it is then filtered like a normal list, by a template-filter. So this should make one trip to the database but the result will be heavier, and the filtering of it will be computed many times in templatefilter rather than telling the databse to do it.

Filter:

@register.filter
def state(mobjects_list, arg):

```
filtered = []
for p in mobjects_list:
    if p.state == arg:
        filtered.append(p)

return filtered
```

And in any templates where the view returns the mobjects I can do

```
for p in mobjects|state:'A'
    ....
```

Which option is preferable, the fastest?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like context processors are what you want. Basically, you can write a context processor that will add some context to every RequestContext. A context processor might look like this (I usually put these in a file project_directory/app_directory/context_processors.py):

```
from project.app.models import Book

def number_of_books(request):
    return {'num_books': Book.objects.all().count()}
```

Then, in your project's settings.py, add this file to the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS tuple:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ('app.context_processors.number_of_books', 'other', 'stuff')
```

Finally, you must make all your view functions use RequestContext instead of plain old Context. Generic views automatically use RequestContext. If you're using render_to_response, you must add a context_instance kwarg ('name' in this example is just a local variable already being passed as context in this view):

```
from django.template import RequestContext

def my_view(request):
    # ... some code, including assigning the 'name' variable to something ...
    return render_to_response("app/template.html", {'name': name},
                       context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My favorite way to ensure I'm using RequestContext is to use the render_to decorator from django-annoying (a third-party collection of convenient things): https://bitbucket.org/offline/django-annoying/wiki/Home

Now, every time a template is rendered, it will have all the normal context variables from its own view *plus the context variables from your context processors*. In my example, your bookstore website could have a line in the header of every single page that says "Now offering 3,141,592 books!" Assuming you have a base template called base.html that all other templates extend, you would accomplish it like this:

```
<div id="header">
  <h1> Cool Online Bookstore </h1>
  <p> Now offering {{ num_books }} books! </p>
</div>
```

Comment: All context processors run *every* time `RequestContext` is instantiated, regardless of whether the variables are needed or not. This can get very expensive very quickly if they always query the database.

Comment: I've thought about this in my past projects, but I've never really had any performance issues stemming from it (not that I've created any high-traffic websites). If you need, for example, a sidebar with a bunch of up-to-date information from your database, I don't know of a better or less expensive way to do it. Is there a better way? Obviously caching would help, depending on how up-to-date you need the information to be.

Comment: Interesting approach baddox. I was looking more into using templatetags, but the problem is I would have to have a kind of duplication, each tag for each filter applied, or I supply one string to filter by to one tag, but then the tag would have "logic" - where to output the stuff, to what snippet. It adds all kinds of complications which I dont like. But the first approach has duplication which I dont like either. And this approach is kind of overhead. It should be rendered only sometime. Could it be done with template filters?

Comment: I have no experience creating template tags or filters (I just use the built in ones), but it seems to me that templates shouldn't be explicitly hitting the database, or even be aware of the database side of things. Context processors do have the problem that they're executed for every single `RequestContext` instantiation, so if you're wanting to do heavy database work and only show it on a few pages, they're probably not the way to go.

Comment: Class-based views can help reduce code duplication, but I'm also inexperienced with those. They are slated for official release in Django 1.3, and there's already documentation here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/

Comment: Alrite Ill check into class-based views. Now I have experimented a while and it works both by templatetags and filters, I cant decide which to use. Ill make an edit of the question with code...